# How to use console.log(); for multiple variables

Tags: javascript, json, console, console.log

I am using p5.js and Kinectron to have one server computer display RGB, Depth, and Skeleton data from another computer over LAN, and it's own kinect.

Using p5.js, I am trying to log two different variables to the console, and I am only able to log one of the variables.

Code:

```
   ...
    function drawJoint(joint) {
      fill(100);
      console.log( "kinect1" + joint);
      // Kinect location data needs to be normalized to canvas size
      ellipse( ( joint.depthX * 300 ) + 400 , joint.depthY * 300 , 15, 15);

      fill(200);

    ...

    function draw2Joint(joint2) {
      fill(100);
      console.log ("kinect2" + joint2);

      // Kinect location data needs to be normalized to canvas size
      ellipse(joint2.depthX * 300 , joint2.depthY * 300, 15, 15);

      fill(200);

      ...
```

When running the above code, the console only shows Joint data from Kinect 1 in real-time, whereas I need both Kinect's Joint data to be logged to the Console.

How can I use console.log for multiple variables/arguments ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know if `draw2Joint` is being executed?

Comment: console.log(var1, var2, var3);

Comment: Please provide a running code so that anyone can debug it and let you know where it lacks.

Comment: Yes, draw2joint is being executed, I know this because when I dont use and console.log(); lines, I can see the Skeleton from 2 kinects on one computer, meaning that function must be working.

Comment: @NullPointer , would I use console.log(var1, var2, var3); inside the function or outside it?

Comment: May be you call calling the 2 function from some where so at  that time you can log

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing multiple arguments to console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746440/passing-multiple-arguments-to-console-log)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will have to use global variables so that you can log them at the same time. Here are the lines of code to add into the functions that you have so far.

```
// add global variables 
var joints1 = null;
var joints2 = null;

function bodyTracked(body) {
  // assign value to joints1
  joints1 = body.joints;
}

function bodyTracked2(body) {
  // assign value to joints2
  joints2 = body.joints;
}

function draw() {
  // log current values at the same time
  console.log(joints1, joints2);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`drawJoint` and `draw2Joint` are called from somewhere so you can `log` **`joint`** 
and **`joint2`** at that time.

```
console.log(joint,joint2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var joint1,jointtwo;
function drawJoint(joint) {
  fill(100);
  joint1=joint;
  // Kinect location data needs to be normalized to canvas size
  ellipse( ( joint.depthX * 300 ) + 400 , joint.depthY * 300 , 15, 15);

  fill(200);

...

function draw2Joint(joint2) {
  fill(100);
   jointtwo=joint2;

  // Kinect location data needs to be normalized to canvas size
  ellipse(joint2.depthX * 300 , joint2.depthY * 300, 15, 15);

  fill(200);

  ...

  console.log(joint1+":"+jointtwo);
```

Comment: Does it matter where the last line,. console.log(joint1+ ":" +jointtwo); goes? Would it be after all the functions or inside a function

Comment: joint1,jointtwo are global variables so you can get the values

Comment: If it is not working...make jsfiddle and send me your full code..i will edit it

Comment: We are getting undefined:undefined in the console.  However, we have been using p5.js editor online and as an application. https://jsfiddle.net/jaytailor15/koLr3zhm/#&togetherjs=KD8zH2atFf

Comment: Check your function calling or not?

Comment: When I run it on the computer application I get a pop up saying "An embedded page on this page says  undefined;undefined "

Comment: Simple..just check this function draw2Joint() working or not..If it will work you can get solution...in your jsfiddle also not working

Comment: the draw2joint function works because we can see the skeleton on the screen, just can't see the joint info that console.log(); helps with.